# verify creation of database objects such as triggers, procedures , permissions

Tags: sql, database, object, verification, creation

I am creating triggers & procedures on a table from a winform application which uses sql server 2005 express.

I want that when the user clicks the create trigger/procedure button, then it creates both the objects & displays on a new Form that triggers & procedures are created with the names and tables on which they are created.

I mean that how do i verify that the objects are created. i want to verify and show it to the user that the objects are created on the so and so table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `CREATE XXX ...`, you can run `SELECT OBJECT_ID('XXX')`

Of course, if you have *no error* the object exists anyway

Comment: sir can i use: 
SELECT * FROM SYS.TRIGGERS , i would then extract the name of the trigger from the result of this query, using reader.Read(), and display it on a new form to show it to the user, but how do i get the table name on which the trigger is created ?

Comment: @sqlchild: if you want. I'd use OBJECT_ID because it works for *every* type of object.

Comment: but sir, using object_id ,  i won't be able to get the trigger name?

Comment: @sqlchild: You already know the trigger name and table name from the CREATE TRIGGER